# How do I properly cast a response from a Firebase Function call in my Flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm teaching myself Flutter by building a simple meal planner app. Part of what I want to do is to use a Firebase function for making calls to the API. I'm using the [Spoonacular API](https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs), and I do not want to store the API key on the app itself, hence the Firebase backend.

I've set up a file called `cloud_functions.dart`, which I plan on using to make calls to my Firebase functions. The call to get the recipes is as follows:

```
Future<SearchRecipesComplexResponseBody> getRecipes() async {
  HttpsCallable callable = getCallable('searchRecipes');
  try {
    final HttpsCallableResult<SearchRecipesComplexResponseBody> results = await callable({'number': 20, 'offset': 0});
    print('Results: ');
    print(results);
    print('Results data:');
    print(results.data);
    return results.data;
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error: ');
    print(e);
    return null;
  }
}

HttpsCallable getCallable(String callableName) {
  FirebaseFunctions functions = FirebaseFunctions.instance;
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print('Running in debug mode');
    functions.useFunctionsEmulator(origin: 'http://localhost:5001');
  }
  return functions.httpsCallable(callableName);
}
```

The code for `SearchRecipesComplexResponseBody` is as follows:

```
import 'package:meal_planner/models/recipe.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'search_recipes_complex_response_body.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class SearchRecipesComplexResponseBody {
  final int offset;
  final int number;
  final List<Recipe> results;
  final int totalResults;

  SearchRecipesComplexResponseBody({this.offset, this.number, this.results, this.totalResults});

  factory SearchRecipesComplexResponseBody.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return _$SearchRecipesComplexResponseBodyFromJson(json);
  }
}
```

The code for `Recipe` is as follows:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Recipe {
  final int id;
  @JsonKey(includeIfNull: false)
  final int calories;
  @JsonKey(includeIfNull: false)
  final String carbs;
  @JsonKey(includeIfNull: false)
  final String fat;
  final String image;
  final String imageType;
  @JsonKey(includeIfNull: false)
  final String protein;
  final String title;

  Recipe({@required this.id, this.calories, this.carbs, this.fat, this.image, this.imageType, this.protein, @required this.title});

  factory Recipe.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return _$RecipeFromJson(json);
  }
}
```

While I do get the data back that I'm expecting, there's something going on with the casting that I get this error when running the code:

`type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`

When I went to debug the code, breaking on the `print(results)` line in the `cloud_functions.dart` file, I saw that the data does seem to match the format that I'm expecting

[image: Unexpanded]
[image: Expanded]

I've attempted to use the [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) utility to generate the JSON serialization code, but that didn't work either. I've tried removing the extraneous fields in the `Recipe` class to no avail.

I think the issue is something to do with the fact that I've got a property on the `SearchRecipesComplexResponseBody` that's a list of `Recipe`s, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. For all I know, I could be barking up the wrong tree. Does anyone have any ideas?

RESOURCES CHECKED:

- Flutterfire Cloud Functions documentation - https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/functions/usage/
- Search on HttpCallableResult - https://duckduckgo.com/?q=flutterfire+httpcallableresult&ia=web
- https://medium.com/codespace69/flutter-working-with-data-json-json-and-serialization-f90165b659d0

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out

I updated the `getRecipes` function in `cloud_functions.dart` to be as follows:

```
Future<SearchRecipesComplexResponseBody> getRecipes() async {
  HttpsCallable callable = getCallable('searchRecipes');
  try {
    final HttpsCallableResult results = await callable({'number': 20, 'offset': 0});
    var convertedResult = Map<String, dynamic>.from(results.data);
    SearchRecipesComplexResponseBody data = SearchRecipesComplexResponseBody.fromJson(convertedResult);
    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error: ');
    print(e);
    return null;
  }
}
```

I saw that I already had a `fromJson` function defined on my `SearchRecipesComplexResponseBody` class, but I hadn't been taking advantage of it. I needed to convert the response I got back from Firebase from an `_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>` to the `Map<String, dynamic>` type that `fromJson` uses.

I also needed to add `anyMap: true` inside my `JsonSerializer` attributes to get the nested list of `Recipe`s in order for its `fromJson`. I'm not sure why that worked. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: It works because `anyMap: true` causes JsonSerialisable to generate code that casts the values in the incoming Json to `Map` instead of `Map<String, dynamic>` - you can see this if you look inside the .g.dart files that JsonSerialisable generates when you run its builder, so really thats all you needed, doing `Map<String, dynamic>.from(results.data);` is not required once you set the `anyMap:true` annotation parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this to convert from `_InternalLinkedHashMap` to `Map<String, dynamic>`. This will get you overcome the error `type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`:

```dart
HttpsCallable callable = functions.httpsCallable('your-function');
final results = await callable();
final data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(results.data);
```